# How to make ActionBar and stacked bar share same background image

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-style-tabhost

is it possible for actionbar and it's stacked bar(one that contain navigation tabs) to share same background image? one that starts from actionbar and ends at stacked bar?

currently the way am implementing this, am ending up having action bar with it own image and stacked bar with its own.

**my styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/app_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/app_yellow</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>

    <item name ="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar</item>

</style>

 <!-- individual ActionBar tabs style -->
<style name="MyTabStyle" parent ="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name ="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name ="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

**in my activity**

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar));
```

Comment: Rather than make them share a background image, it makes more sense to me to make the actionbar and stacked bar transparent and reveal a background image underneath.

Comment: @DaveS  how can you do that and my activity by the way is having a different background image?

Comment: You'd have to set an app level background image then have a parent layout underneath the actionbar that has the desired "main" background image. Then you set the actionbar background to transparent to reveal the app level image. Just something worth trying. I've moved away from action bars in my apps personally because they are so difficult to customize.

Comment: You could also try determining if the action bar is split then load two different drawables that line up together, otherwise use the single drawable you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105473/determine-if-action-bar-is-split

Comment: Don't rely on the old `ActionBar`. Google's moving away from that as a pattern anyway. Use `Toolbar` instead. You can still treat it as you would an `ActionBar` by inflating menus, setting header text, etc. But you're also able to put other views inside of it. Look at their [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). To do what you want to do, you'd include a `TabLayout` inside a `Toolbar`. Couldn't be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *Michael De Soto* guidance(see his comment above), i was able to have actionbar and stacked bar share same background image by using a toolbar that has

- actionbar details(e.g icons,titles) in views(textview for titles, imageviews for icons etc)
- Stacked bar details(basically tabs) in a tablayout.

[image: my output]
**Here how i implemented it guys**

**my activity xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
  >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="President"
            android:id="@+id/appname_1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/myCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appname_1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appname_1"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**added the following in my styles.xml**

```
<style name="mainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>

<style name="myCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**Finally, my activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

TabLayout tabLayout;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityBar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
     mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
              return Item1fragment.newInstance();
            case 1:

                return Item2fragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Item3fragment.newInstance();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Item1;
            case 1:
              return "Item2";
            case 2:
               return "Item3";
        }
        return "";
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your indepth answer OP. For those coming here in future, if you want to display the back button on the toolbar, it will push all the subsequent views in the `Toolbar` to the side by about 50dp, even when aligned below, even when using `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`. Because of this, I have just gone for the transparent backgrounds and having a view behind them.